# How to automate selecting a date from jQuery UI date selector in Selenium RC?

Tags: java, jquery, jquery-ui, selenium-rc

There are 2 date fields, DateField1 and DateField2. On clicking on either of the fields, jQuery UI date selector becomes available. 'DateField1' has a default value of current date. The user needs to select date for 'DateField2'. How to automate this scenario using Selenium RC and Junit.

Answer (score 0):

You can use focus and key input, such as 2011-07-08 for the 8th July last year. JQuery UI date controls can handle direct keyboard input, although they hide the text input field.

Comment: yes, they can handle direct keyboard input. but in case if we want to automate selecting date from the UI datepicker, is there any way to do it?

Comment: Yes. You have to click on the datepicker using selenium and you have to select the date. You can record it in selenium IDE.

Comment: Priti, seems like you aren't aware that Selenium is a way of automating a browser. A keyboard-typing into a box is one of the interactions it can automate for you as part of a test. Lists of the possible 'commands' are at http://release.seleniumhq.org/selenium-core/0.8.0/reference.html . The command in question can be found by searching for the phrase "type ( locator,value )" in the reference, describing its function as "Sets the value of an input field, as though you typed it in." To start understanding Selenium, best visit the documentation at http://seleniumhq.org/docs/